# A function to get the intersection elements of any given number of arrays containing strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following functions that returns the intersection of the elements between some arrays of strings.

Initially it was meant to handle only 2 arrays, but I started having the need for it to handle more than 2, so I added the conditional `return` to make it recursive.

How can I make it flexible enough so it will be able to handle any number of arrays (equal or greater than 2, of course).

I though about using `...rest` parameters, but I don't know how to do this, yet.

```
function intersection(list1, list2, list3, list4) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      let item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }
  if (list3 && list4) {
    return intersection(result,list3,list4);
  }
  if (list3) {
    return intersection(result,list3);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
function intersection(list1, list2, list3, list4) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      let item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }
  if (list3 && list4) {
    return intersection(result,list3,list4);
  }
  if (list3) {
    return intersection(result,list3);
  }
  return result;
}

const x1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const x2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
const x3 = ['a','b','c'];
const x4 = ['a','b'];

console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2)));
```

Comment: `function blah(...args)` .... then you can access the arguments using `args[0]` `args[1]` etc

Comment: MDN has some good info on [*rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a recursion, you could take [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and for getting the intersection a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter against it.

```js
function intersection(...arrays) {
    return arrays.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b)));
}

console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']));
console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Version with recursion

```js
function intersection(a, b = [], ...arrays) {
    var i = a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b));
    return arrays.length
         ? intersection(i, ...arrays)
         : i;
}

console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']));
console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(intersection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Comment: Nice answer! Performance-wise, is this faster than iterating over the arrays? Or does it do that under the hood? I have zero experience using `Set` in Javascript.

Comment: it should be faster, because by using nested loops, you have o(n*m) vs nearly o(n+m) with a set.

Comment: Thanks, Nina! If you can, could you explain to me what is that filter function doing? I know to use `filter` on an array. But somehow the way you've used it seems magic to me. Doesn't it expect a callback to use it on each element? And the `new Set(b)` is being used as the `this argument` ? Is that right? I'm reading all about it on MDN but I still coudn't get wrap my head around it.

Comment: the set is `thisArg` and the callback is the prototype of `has`. this is just a function without a bound set. if no `thisArg` would available, then this would work as well: `Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(b))`. you could use `this` inside of the callback directly, if a `thisArg` is supplied.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I think I get it now! I didn't know that the `filter` callback is implicitly run against each item of the array. I always used it explicitly inline, like: `['a','b','c','d','e'].filter((item) => ['a','b','c'].includes(item))`.

Comment: Depending on the requirements, if you want to avoid duplicate values you may want to convert the first array into a `Set` as well `(a, b) => [... new Set(a)].filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b))`

Answer (score 1):

Nina's answer is of course greater, but I also post to propose a solution based on your own code.

---

As your function needs at least two lists, then precise them in your argument list. Then, use destructuring for the facultative ones.

Then, if there is at least one facultative list, re-execute your function by specifying the second parameter as the first facultative one. Use `Array#shift` to remove it from the list. Don't forget to put your new facultative list.

```js
function intersection(list1, list2, ...lists) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      let item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }
  
  if (lists.length) {
    return intersection(result, lists.shift(), ...lists);
  }
  
  return result;
}

const x1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const x2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
const x3 = ['a','b','c'];
const x4 = ['a','b'];

console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2)));
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for, at first. I will still use it with a minor change to intersect arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another function which compares two arrays and returns the intersection. In the `intersection` function, get the arrays passed as a 2D array called `lists` using [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to intersect the arrays with `compare` as the callback

```js
function compare(list1, list2) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      let item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }

  return result
}

function intersection(...lists) {
  return lists.reduce(compare)
}

const x1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const x2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
const x3 = ['a','b','c'];
const x4 = ['a','b'];

console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3,x4)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2,x3): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2,x3)));
console.log('Intersection(x1,x2): ' + JSON.stringify(intersection(x1,x2)));
```

**Note:** You can probably simplify the implementation of `compare`. This is just to demonstrate with your existing code